# Session object becomes null on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, session

So, I developed an application in MVC on C#. Everything works perfectly and smooth locally.

I decided to mount the whole thing on Microsoft Azure. My Session object becomes null for some reason, causing a session expires because of my validations. This is random, sometimes after some seconds, sometimes after a minute. I am sure this is not because of time of inactivity because it happens when I am clicking on things.

This is my login method where I create my object:

```
    public ActionResult Login(MyWebApplication.Models.LoginRQ User)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            MyWebApplication.Models.LoginRS login = new MyWebApplication.Models.LoginRS();
            try
            {
                MyWebApplication.LoginBusiness LoginProxy = new MyWebApplication.LoginBusiness();
                login = LoginProxy.Login(User);

                if (login.Logged == false)
                {
                    ViewBag.MessageError = Wrong user";
                }

                Session["InfoUser"] = login;
                return RedirectToAction("Index","Inicio");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.MessageError = ex.Message;
            }

        }
        return View(User);
    }
```

This is my validation on every method:

```
    public static bool ValidateSession(MyWebApplication.Models.LoginRS InfoUser)
    {
        if (InfoUser == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("SESSION EXPIRED");
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I use this validation when instanciating a method from my business layer. For example, this is my business layer for Customer CRUD:

public class CustomerBusiness
    {
        internal MyWebApplication.Models.LoginRS InfoUser;
        internal MyWebApplication.Models.Customer OBJRES_Residentes = new MyWebApplication.Models.Customer();

```
    [Logger]
    public CustomerBusiness(MyWebApplication.Models.LoginRS InfoUser)
    {
        MyWebApplication.LoginBusiness.ValidateSession(InfoUser);
        this.InfoUser = InfoUser;
    }
```

}
As you can see, I need the InfoUser so I log the userName on CRUD operations.

This is part of my WebConfig:

```
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout ="20" cookieless="false"></sessionState>
    <customErrors mode="Off">
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
```

No lets talk about how I configured this on Azure. I created a WebApplication and a SQL Server Azure DB. This is an image:

[Azure_Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk4BX.png)

This is so frustrating that I am thinking about using DB cache, even when I know the performance would be affected.

Any ideas? I really appreciate your help guys

Comment: Where is this validation method invoked?

Comment: What happens if you use system.web.httpcontext.current.session instead ?

Comment: How did you deploy: Web apps? How are you managing your session: in-proc? Please edit your question with more details.

Comment: Hi my friends. Thanks for your answers. I updated my question with firther details. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it in the wrong way. You should have your own State Server, rather than storing the session on the web server. The idea of using Azure, is to add elastic scale when needed.

Here a few options:

1-Add Azure Redis Cache and make it your session manager to all instances of your web app;

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider/

2-Use Sql Database to manage the state.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-sql-azure-for-session-state/

Comment: I agree. If he has multiple instances there is no guarantee Azure will always route the request to the instance where session was created.